# Hide empty dismissable Bootstrap alert with CSS?

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm using bootstrap 3 alerts to display inline form errors. Conveniently I'm able to hide empty alerts using the following CSS rule:

```
.alert:empty{
    display:none;
}
```

I'd like to make these alerts dismissable using bootstrap's JS. Bootstrap's example markup is as follows:

```
<div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissible" role="alert">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">
        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span>
    </button>
</div>
```

But now the alerts are never ":empty" as they hold the dismiss button. Is there any way to hide (when empty excluding the button markup) these  alerts using pure CSS or am I stuck with JS?

Answer (score 0):

Here, basicly after every alert you need script that check if message `div` is empty. If is empty js code hide alert marked with id:

JSFiddle: [here](http://jsfiddle.net/1tn0r87c/1/)

```
function hideAlert(id){
    var text = $('#'+id+' .message').text();
    console.log(text.length);    //white spaces, new lines counts to
    if(text.length <= 0)
        $('#'+id).hide();
}
```